# Cannot cast contents of TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, casting, .net-4.0

I have something of an oddity.
My MVC4 project is having issues in casting the contents of model objects in TempData. I can see the object's correctly defined within TempData using the watch window, but casting fails, throwing no exception whatsoever.

Is there a config / project setting which messes up casting / what's in TempData?

For instance, given a simple model:

```
namespace NewProject.Models
{
    public class MyList
    {
        public List<string> Cars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The following code fails to cast the object back out

```
    Models.List l = new Models.MyList();
    List<string> cars = new List<string>();
    cars.Add("VW");
    cars.Add("Ford");
    l.Cars = cars;
    TempData["Cars"] = l;


    Models.MyList _cars = (Models.MyList)TempData["Cars"];
```

The above code works in a brand new project, but not in my main project, where setting a watch on _cars above is listed as

```
    The name '_cars' does not exist in the current context
```

...after the cast has taken place. i.e. It's not even null..

The exact same thing happens if I use session instead of TempData.

UPDATE:

- Please note that the code as listed above should work - there is nothing
  specifically wrong with it.
- I can create a new project and it works as it should do. It's simply not working on my (main) Web project.
- The same project when opened in VS2013 Express for Web shows the same
  symptoms - i.e. it's not casting at all. It's therefore not a VS2012
  specific issue.

Comment: Same code is working, where is the code in which you are getting the error?

Comment: That code does work in a new project, however the exact same code does not work in my "work" project. I can't see anything specifically wrong with the code, I'm wondering what may break that simple code as that's what I'm facing.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing

```
Models.MyList _cars = TempData["Cars"] as Models.MyList;
```

And more over the exception looks like related to scope and context of the variable declaration. Check whether the variable scope exists in the place where you were adding a watch expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that doesn't work either. It *should* but it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 3):

Just try with

`var _cars = TempData["Cars"] as List<string>;` or

`var _cars=  (List<string>)TempData["Cars"];`.

First one is better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work in my project either. Something fundamental is broken in my install, and I can't get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is too late to answer to this. Usually I use castable feature like ViewBag. You assign the **TempData["YourTempData"]** into **ViewBag.YourVewBag**. Then, you can cast it.

1) Assign that TempData["YourObject"] into a ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.YourNewViewBag = TempData["YourObject"];
```

2) Consume the ViewBag:

```
var objVariable = ViewBag.YourObject as List<YourClass>;
foreach(var item in objVariavle)
{
    //...........
}
```

This is how I do, ViewBag is castable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with this code. The error has nothing to do with casting. It's telling you quite literally that you're referencing `_cars` in a context where it doesn't exist. This is most commonly due to using something like an `if` statement. For example:

```
if (something)
{
    var foo = "bar";
}

var baz = foo; // Error!
```

To fix it, you need to define the variable in a parent scope first:

```
string foo;

if (something)
{
    foo = "bar";
}
```

Comment: Chris I agree with with what you say 100%... However the "current context" error is in the watch window in the line *after* _cars is defined and not outside of the scope where it is defined. Its nuts. Never seen this...

Comment: What is that next line? You haven't included it in the code here. Perhaps that might shed light on what's causing the issue.

Comment: Alas the next line are nothing to do with it. The lines above we're put into the main project from a simple test project to test I wasn't going nuts, as the lines in my main project getting the objects were not working in the same way. Something in the solution isn't working how it should, and the only thing I can think of is start the solution and  /or project file from scratch..